# IIS 7.5 redirect user if they are using SSLv2 or SSLv3

Tags: iis-7.5, windows-server-2008-r2

I want to redirect all users still using SSLv2 and SSLv3 to a specific page and users with no SSLv3 protocol (TLS 1.x) will no redirect to the page.

So how do I detect these SSLv2-SSLv3-only users from IIS? and put in place the redirection.